# Return values from other workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Have a question about formula which will resolve my issue.
In my main workbook I need to compare data from two sources.
One of the columns must retrieve data(amounts) from other workbook.
I want formula which will search for all amounts in column G and will skip all blank cells. Tried to use VLOOKUP, INDEX and SMALL functions but no effect.
Each day amounts are different and I need to match them in main file and find exeptions.

Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: At the same time I want this result of formula to showed up at the height of same amount in next column :)

Comment: Will need some sample data - hard to tell what you want just from the description

Comment: Picture added to Q. Don't want to use VLOOKUP functions because amounts are not equal every day.

Comment: If any of the below solutions solved your problem please mark the question closed like so: http://stackoverflow.com/tour Otherwise, please let me know what's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an array formula such as the following?

```
=INDEX($G$2:$G$20,SMALL(IF(($G$2:$G$20)=0,"",ROW($G$2:$G$20)),ROW()-1)-ROW($G$2:$G$20)+1)
```

The formula would have to be placed into cell `I2` as an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) (which must be entered pressing `Strg` + `Shift` + `Enter`). Then you can drag down the formula to get all the other values.

It doesn't have to be in column `I` but it has to be in row `2` because this formula get's the n-th Number from the list which is not = 0. The n-th place is (in this formula) `row()-1`. So for row 2 it will be `2-1=1` and thus the 1st number. By dragging down the formula you get the 2nd, 3rd, etc. number. If you start with the formula in cell `I5` instead then it would have to be adjusted to be as follows:

```
=INDEX($G$2:$G$20,SMALL(IF(($G$2:$G$20)=0,"",ROW($G$2:$G$20)),ROW()-4)-ROW($G$2:$G$20)+1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That worked! but still their is blank cell as result. There is no #num or #value but blank cell. In next cell I have value wihich is next in array. Formula took empty cell with "space" as <>0 value?

Comment: If you want, just send me the file and I'll insert the formula for you. BTW, there is no space between the two quotation marks and the formula is `=0` and not `<>0`. The latter is merely due to the fact that the `IF` statement is followed by the `True` clause (in which I entered the `""`). If you prefer `=0` then you just need to swap the `""` with the `False` condition. But as I said, you may also send me the file if you prefer.

Comment: Everythink works perfectly. I have to add nested if in if function to works on my workbooks. NOW I have another wrinkle to solve. I have used this formula: `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$7,0),"",A1)` but this give me exactly same value like in column A. Sometime my data is slightly diffrent for example: 1000,52 don't MATCH 1000,53. I wanted to add ROUND but it didnt helped me. I want from MATCH function to inclued this little diffrence in calculations.

Comment: I am glad to hear that this solution solved your problem. Feel free to mark the question closed / accepted. If you have another question to ask, I'd recommend that you post another **new** question. It is important to separate questions from one another because this website is not only meant to be a solution for you but (moreover so) a work of reference for anybody seeking for advice / help when they are looking for answers to their problems. If there is another "nested" question within this question then nobody will find it. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: The formula you are probably looking for in the above comment is `{=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(ROUND(A1,0), ROUND($B$1:$B$7, 0),0)), "", ROUND(A1,0))}`. Note that this is (once again) an array formula.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the column and store each value >0 in an array and then compare or you loop through the column and compare directly...

something like:

```
Dim i as Integer = 0
Foreach value in Maintable
    Do 
    If otherworkbook.cells(i,7) = value Then '7 for G
     do your stuff
    End If
    i = i + 1
    While i < otherworkbook.rows.count
Next
```

I think that could be the right approach

Comment: I was also thinking about macro but it would take to much time because I need to compare 30 different files for each 30 tables. I was thinking about something more static ;)